# How to define reference_docx in rmarkdown file using pandoc 2.1

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I downloaded the latest version of RStudio and then upgraded to pandoc 2.1 because I wanted to control the custom table setting in the output .docx file.

However, in the previous version of pandoc with RStudio (1.9) the following YAML produced the correct .docx file:

```
---
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx= ../support/word/rmd_styles.docx
    toc: true
    fig_caption: true
---
```

But when I upgraded to pandoc 2.1 (and verified it in RStudio console with):

```
> rmarkdown:::find_pandoc()
> as.list(rmarkdown:::.pandoc)
$version
[1] ‘2.1’
```

The reference to the .docx file in the YAML above no longer works and I get the following error:

```
--reference-docx has been removed. Use --reference-doc instead.
Try pandoc.exe --help for more information.
```

So when I switch `reference_docx` to `reference_doc` (not sure if that is correct?) I get the following error:

```
--reference-docx has been removed. Use --reference-doc instead.
Try pandoc.exe --help for more information.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 2
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/Prevost~1.PRE/AppData/Roaming/local/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Report.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output Report.docx --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --highlight-style tango --reference-docx "..\support\word\rmd_styles.docx"' had status 2 
Execution halted
```

Hopefully I am just using the incorrect syntax in the YAML but I'm not sure what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with the rmarkdown package 1.6 and I solved it by updating to rmarkdown 1.8. You may do so by executing the following code

`install.packages('rmarkdown')`

and the loading it by executing

`library(rmarkdown)`

Comment: Good point...it is still loading v1.6 even though I am using install.packages("rmarkdown") and the CRAN version is 1.8...I'm probably missing something and I'll have to get it updated to see if it works